# FontMetrics: TextBound invalid

Tags: android, textview, logcat, android-logcat, fontmetrics

What is the meaning of this warning??, im getting it when i set a text in a `TextView`:

```
10-30 23:56:42.122: W/TextPaint(1366): FontMetrics: TextBound invalid!!! top:-32 text:00:05:50
```